# Swift/XCode 6.4: class from UITableViewController has no initializers

Tags: xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a class as an extension of UITableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailsMyTasksViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var backButton : UIButton!
var detailItem: Task

@IBAction func backToHome(sender : AnyObject) {
    /*dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("selectedTasksToHome", sender: self)
    }*/
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 11 /* number of Task information/attributes --> 11 rows */
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SelectedMyTaskDetails", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Task id"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(self.detailItem.id)
        break
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Titolo"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.detailItem.titolo
        break
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Oggetto"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.detailItem.oggetto
        break
    case 3:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Check mail abilitato"
        if (self.detailItem.check_mail) {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Abilitato"
        }
        else {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Non abilitato"
        }
        break
    case 4:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Progetto id"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(self.detailItem.id_progetto)
        break
    case 5:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Progetto nome"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.detailItem.progetto_nome
        break
    case 6:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Assegnato a"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.detailItem.assegnato_a
        break
    case 7:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Richiesto da"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.detailItem.richiesto_da
        break
    case 8:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Priorità"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.detailItem.priorita
        break
    case 9:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Termine consegna"
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.detailItem.termine_consegna)
        break
    case 10:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Stato"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.detailItem.stato
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    return cell
}

}
```

I don't know where is the problem because I get the error in title when I try to compile. Moreover I have another class similar to this into another table view controller and it works perfectly and also in that class there is no initializer. What's the problem no?

**UPDATE**
I don't know why but I just changed

```
var detailItem: Task
```

with

```
var detailItem: Task?
```

and it works. What's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the var detailItem you said it is of the type Task. Without the '?' detailItem can not be nil so it MUST have a value. But with the code

```
var detailItem: Task
```

you don't give it a value (it is empty and that is forbidden). But if you set an initializer to your class in wich you set the value of detailItem, the object of DetailsMyTasksViewController will never have a detailItem without a value and this would be possible.

By adding the '?' to Task you say that detailItem can be empty (nil) so it is set to nil by default.

So finally xcode doesn't tell you what the error is it tells you what you might want to do to fix it.

For conclusion:
-The error: You say detailItem can not be nil but you don't give it a value.
-1. solution: add a '?' to say it can be nil
          -2. solution: add an initializer to your class
-3. solution: do something like:

```
    var detailItem: Task = Task(...)
```

Comment: Thank you mate, it was very enlightening and useful for me to better understand. Thank you from heart :)

Comment: No problem I remember me seeing this error the first time and understanding it not really ;)